# Which one is correct and why?

Tags: sentence-choice, conjugations

I think the correct one is the number 2 but I'm not sure.

1. I love all what she do.
2. I love all what she does.

Thank you very much,

Comment: Why do you think that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Neither is correct.  What would be correct is

> I love all that she does.

However, this sounds a little odd.  I would instead recommend:

> I love everything she does.

Comment: what about this: I love what she does?